# calling methods via ajax and return a variable spring mvc 4

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm learning spring mvc 4 and I'm using thymeleaf as the template engine ... I have a simple question .. I have a list of products to be viewed and the user can click on a like button for example.

From what I've learnt, the html elements calls the server side controllers via href (ajax or not) which will call the appropriate method using the request mapping, but these methods returns a string that represents the view name .. but I don't want to return a view, for example, when the user hits like, I just want to call a method that modifies the DB and return a boolean and based on it I change the color of the like button if the DB modification succeeded or an error message if failed .. how can I do that?

**EDIT**
Here is a simple example of what I'm trying to achieve (just submit ajax request when a like button is clicked on a product so i can update the DB for the user and return whether the like insertion into DB succeeded or not)

Thymeleaf Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initialscale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<title>Home</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"
    th:href="@{https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
    th:integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
    th:crossorigin="anonymous" />
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"
    th:href="@{https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css}"
    th:integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r"
    th:crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr th:each="prod : ${products}">
                        <td th:text="${prod.id}">Id</td>
                        <td th:text="${prod.name}">Product Name</td>
                        <td th:text="${prod.desc}">Product Description</td>
                        <td>
                            <div th:id="${prod.id}">
                                <button id="like-btn">Like</button>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script
        th:src="@{https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:inline="javascript">
    $("#like-btn").click(function() {
        var divId = $(this).parent().attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: ("http://localhost:9090/like?prodId=" + divId),
            success: function(){alert("Submit succeeded");},
            fail: function(){alert("Submit failed");}
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Spring Controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController
{
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String getHomePage()
    {
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/products")
    public String getProducts(Model model)
    {
        ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

        Product p1 = new Product();
        p1.setId(1);
        p1.setName("Product 1");
        p1.setDesc("Product 1 Description");
        products.add(p1);

        Product p2 = new Product();
        p2.setId(2);
        p2.setName("Product 2");
        p2.setDesc("Product 2 Description");
        products.add(p2);

        model.addAttribute("products", products);

        return "products";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/like", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public boolean likePage(@RequestParam("prodId") int productId)
    {
        System.out.println("Prod ID:  " + productId);
        //DB insert and modification and return result code, just a sample here
        //to be processed by jquery
        //if(insertionSucceeded)
            return true;
        //else
        //  return false;
    }
}
```

but of course this gives an error that says there is no template called like.

Comment: Do you want to do this in ajax?

Comment: yes, i want to do it in ajax

Comment: @Lucky I edited the question with a simple example of what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code,

```
$("#like-btn").click(function(){
    var prodLikeId = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $.ajax(function(){
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://localhost:9090/like?prodId="+prodLikeId,
        success: function(response){
            alert("Submit succeeded"+response);
            if(response===true){
                window.alert("Update the HTML");
                //update the like button color here
                $('#like-btn').css('color','blue');
            }
        },
        error: function(e){
            alert("Submit failed"+e);
        }
    });
});
```

And in your Controller, you need to add `@ResponseBody` annotation and `produces = "application/json"` for your ajax methods,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/like", method=RequestMethod.GET,produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody Boolean likePage(@RequestParam("prodId") int productId)
{
    System.out.println("Prod ID:  " + productId);
    //DB insert and modification and return result code, just a sample here
    //to be processed by jquery
    //int res = productService.insertProductLike(productId);
    //if(res>0)
        return true;
    //else
    //  return false;
}
```

Use Firebug like tools to inspect the ajax calls and to verify the request-response data. Or you could also use a `Map<String,String>` as your method type and return the response by filling up the map like `map.put("success","true");`. This will return a json string response like,

```
{"success":"true"}
```

based on this key-value pair json response you can access this in the success block with `response.success` and correspondingly show or update data in the HTML.

Comment: thx a lot .. this works great though I'm having trouble with spring security now since I'm using rest .. but the solution is right, my problem now is with configuring spring security for both rest and normal controllers .. thx